# What is the difference between "on-chain-metadata" and "metadata" in the Blockfrost Endpoint

Tags: nft, metadata, blockfrost

I am fetching my assets using the Blockfrost endpoint for a specific asset:

[https://docs.blockfrost.io/#tag/Cardano-Assets/paths/~1assets~1{asset}/get](https://docs.blockfrost.io/#tag/Cardano-Assets/paths/%7E1assets%7E1%7Basset%7D/get)

But there are two metadata entries, one for "on-chain metadata" and one only says "metadata", I have read that metadata is also saved off chain. I think it may be the case for the second option, is it the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

- `onchain_metadata` refers to the metadata stored on the Blockchain, according to: [CIP0025](https://github.com/cardano-foundation/CIPs/blob/master/CIP-0025/README.md)
- `metadata` refers to off chain metadata, stored on [Cardano Token registry](https://github.com/cardano-foundation/cardano-token-registry)